# How to add a new item in listbox which binding from code behind to xaml page

Tags: c#, wpf

```
ProjectInformation instance = lstbxindex.SelectedItem as ProjectInformation;
string name = instance.ProjectRow.Name;
IEditableCollectionView items = lstbxindex.Items;
if(items.CanRemove)
{
    items.Remove(lstbxindex.SelectedItem);
}
```

Using these lines of code remove listboxitems. after edit the values I need to add the values in listbox.

XAML

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding}" HorizontalContentAlignment="Left" x:Name="lstbxindex" SelectionMode="Extended" Foreground="White" FontSize="20px" Height="241" BorderBrush="#555555" Margin="10,34,16,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="322" Background="#555555" >
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <WrapPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="5" >
                <TextBlock Height="40px" Width="80px" Text="{Binding Roundedhour1}" FontSize="24" Background="#555555"  Foreground="Black"></TextBlock>
                <Label x:Name="items" Content="{Binding ProjectRow.Name}" Margin="35,0,0,0" MouseDoubleClick="items_MouseDoubleClick" Foreground="White"></Label>
            </WrapPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

Comment: You should be [getting error](http://stackoverflow.com/q/27348796/1997232) when trying to add items. Where do you set `DataContext`? What type is the data? It has to be [`ObservableCollection<>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms668604(v=vs.110).aspx) and then simply use `Add`/`Insert` method of that collection to add/insert items into `ListBox`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Adding an item to a bound WPF ListBox](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1307067/adding-an-item-to-a-bound-wpf-listbox)

Comment: I'm not used observable collection.

Comment: If you plan to add/remove items then `ObservableCollection` is the right choice. Other option is to *refresh* `ItemsSource` by setting it to `null` and then back to modified collection.

Answer (score 1):

Set the `ItemsSource` property of the `ListBox` to an `ObservableCollection<ProjectInformation>` and add and remove items from this Collection using the `Add` and `Remove` methods.

**XAML:**

```
<ListBox HorizontalContentAlignment="Left" x:Name="lstbxindex" SelectionMode="Extended" Foreground="White" FontSize="20px" Height="241" BorderBrush="#555555" Margin="10,34,16,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="322" Background="#555555" >
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <WrapPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="5" >
                <TextBlock Height="40px" Width="80px" Text="{Binding Roundedhour1}" FontSize="24" Background="#555555"  Foreground="Black"></TextBlock>
                <Label x:Name="items" Content="{Binding ProjectRow.Name}" Margin="35,0,0,0" MouseDoubleClick="items_MouseDoubleClick" Foreground="White"></Label>
            </WrapPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

**Code:**

```
public class ProjectInformation
{
    public int Roundedhour1 { get; set; }
}

public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    private ObservableCollection<ProjectInformation> _sourceCollection = new ObservableCollection<ProjectInformation>();
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        lstbxindex.ItemsSource = _sourceCollection;

        //add
        ProjectInformation item = new ProjectInformation() { Roundedhour1 = 1 };
        _sourceCollection.Add(item);
    }

    private void items_MouseDoubleClick(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        //remove
        _sourceCollection.Remove(lstbxindex.SelectedItem as ProjectInformation);
    }
}
```